# How to get exact length of wave data with MediaFoundationReader?

Tags: naudio, ms-media-foundation

While reading a WAVE file as binary data, I get the length of 'data' chunk from corresponding bytes ([Subchunk2Size](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)).

But when I use NAudio MediaFoundationReader I get sligtly different data size value, because it's *calculated* as:

```
    private long GetLength(IMFSourceReader reader)
    {
        ...
        var lengthInBytes = (((long)variant.Value) * waveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond) / 10000000L;
        ...
        return lengthInBytes;
    }
```

Is there a way to get exact data length witn NAudio MediaFoundationReader?

Comment: If you want the data length in bytes of a WAV file, why not just use NAudio's WaveFileReader and look at the Length property?

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your lib. I use MediaFoundationReader, because I want read the sound from as many audio *and video* types as it possible. And MediaFoundationReader do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with for first time: use `List<Int32>` instead of `array` to store the data, so I don't need to know exact data length now.

The next solution - is to extract sound data to temp wav file with `MediaFoundationReader` and process its data later on with `WaveFileReader` (and `Length` property). Here how I've done it:

```
    private void ExtractAndResampleAudio(WaveFormat resampleFormat)
    {
        using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(this.Filename))
        {
            if (NeedResample(reader.WaveFormat, resampleFormat))
            {
                using (var resampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(reader, CreateOutputFormat(resampleFormat)))
                {
                    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(this.TempFilename, resampler);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(this.TempFilename, reader);
            }
        }
    }
```

This solution has a strange side effect - on Windows 7 `MediaFoundationReader` extract slightly less data. On Windows 8 length of copied data match source file. I've posted an issue to NAudio project: https://naudio.codeplex.com/workitem/16453